# can anyone help me find error here in apex code

Tags: apex, inheritance

```java
public virtual class Animal {

    public virtual void description(){
        System.debug('I AM AN ANIMAL');
    }
    
    public virtual void comm(){
        
        System.debug('I CAN COMMUNICATE');
    }
    
}
```

```java
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public override void description(){
        System.debug('I AM A CAT');
    }
    public override void comm(){
        System.debug('MEOW MEOW');
    }

}
```

[image]

```java
Animal a1=new Animal();
Animal c=new Cat();

c.description();

c.comm();
```

Comment: Looks to me like you need to save both your `Animal` and `Cat` classes. It appears that you didn't initially define the `Animal` methods as virtual, and `Cat` didn't initially extend `Animal`.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've provided, as written, is fine and shouldn't run into any syntax errors.

And by running all of that code via Anonymous Apex, I can confirm that it does run without issue.
You can define classes in anon apex (as long as they don't have any static methods or variables or inner classes, which these don't), so it's pretty literally just mashing all 3 of those snippets together.

The issue you're running into looks to be that:

- Your two classes haven't been saved
- Your Animal class didn't initially define its methods as virtual
- Your Cat class didn't initially extend the Animal class

Get your two classes to save (you likely need to save `Animal` first), and it should work.